# How does Bloons TD 5 on the PS4/PS5 keep track of the Daily Chest Reward

Tags: ps4, ps5, bloons-td-5

How does it keep track of when the game was last played? If you disconnect the internet and change the date and time and play the game it still knows the last time the game was opened?